# Is there anyway to fill in a form without user input with .net CF 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, windows-ce

I am working with windows ce for an application that needs to be authenticated before use. I don't want the end user to have to enter a username and password which is static everytime the device is turned on. Is there any way to do something like that? I was able to acheive it in a windows form application but i haven't seen anything on Stack or in the MSDN that will help me do that. My code for the forms app is below but it wont work in the Compact Framework.

```
//string doc = webBrowser1.DocumentText;
        //HtmlElement userValue = doc.GetElementById("username");
        //userValue.SetAttribute("value", "devacc");
        //HtmlElement passValue = doc.GetElementById("password");
        //passValue.SetAttribute("value", "zzq15354");
        //HtmlElement subButton = doc.GetElementById("submit");
        //subButton.InvokeMember("click");
```

Comment: Instead of trying to patch the HTML and simulating a user-click, maybe you could directly invoke the web service and send the "devacc"/"zzq15354" credentials using an `HttpWebRequest`. Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529547/webrequest-with-post-parameters-in-net-compact-framework) ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your going to need to verify user/device another way. I would probably save the devices MEID(Dec) # (which is unique) to your user data then allow access if signed in ON that specific hardware.. Here is a thread on how to find that number [Find Serial Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322234/how-to-find-serial-number-of-android-device)

Comment: this is just to access an api so i dont have the access to let it through without the username and password. It would be fairly simple if i could find the html element and just input it there.

Comment: You could still store the MEID and associate it with a user and pass then write a conditional if userid & pass is associated ... proceed.. You could also store the user and pass on device and call it from there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925486/android-storing-username-and-password

Comment: this is the type of authorization that needs to be done. Im not sure if i can use the MEID for this since im not passing the values as a parameter or field. http://imgur.com/m7uC1rq

Comment: You need to re word your question more clearly so i can understand exactly what your wanting to accomplish ... After viewing the picture you have me a little confused in the direction you want

Comment: I want to be able to fill in the username and password on start up so nothing has to be manually entered.

Comment: the only way you'll be able to do that is based off of previously storing your user name/password and then keying off of a unique identifier of the device to ensure its actually that user... The only way i know of to do that is to store the user/pass, check the device MEID (or other unique identifier), and if they match ... post